# AttributeError: decoding error while running Python tweepy script in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, error-handling, tweepy, attributeerror

I have a Python 3.5 script which essentially is a Twitter scraper that collects tweets using the *tweepy* package and its *StreamListener* function.

Now my script runs perfectly within the Command shell but when I try to run it on the Ubuntu environment of my server I receive a decoding error.

```
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
self._start(async)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
self._run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
raise exception
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 247, in _run
verify=self.verify)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 454, in reque                                                                                                             st
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 388, in prepa                                                                                                             
re_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 297, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 490, in prepare                                                                                                             _auth
   r = auth(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 7                                                                                                             1, in __call__
r.url = to_native_str(r.url)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 1                                                                                                             4, in to_native_str
return string.decode('utf-8')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

This makes sense because you can't decode a string which already is a string. But my question is how I can solve this issue because this is an error occuring within a package?

Comment: You're probably trying to decode a string which is already decoded!

Comment: Are you running `python3.5` on the ubuntu machine?

Comment: I am running python 3.5.2 on the ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem comes from **requests-oauthlib**, you are running an old version of it, and the problem seems to have been fixed since 4.0.1 .

Upgrade your system (the packaged version with Ubuntu 16.10 is 7.0):

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

Or install using pip:

```
sudo pip3 install requests-oauthlib
```

Comment: Good suggestion but unfortunately it does not solve the issue. I updated the packages and re-installed requests-oauthlib through `sudo apt install python3-requests-oauthlib` but it will return the same error.

Comment: Did you try from pip? If it fails to, maybe try installing from github?